# CS50 pset7 Houses import.py prolem

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

My script runs & I don't receive any errors but my students.db is always empty.
My print commands for debugging all seem to print the contents of the csv.
I guess it could the be insert but I can't find an issue with it.
My code is below, along with what I see when I try to view the DB through the CS50IDE.
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import cs50
import csv
from sys import argv, exit

#if len(argv) != 2:
#    print("Usage: python import.py characters.csv")
#    exit(1)

# connect to db
db = cs50.SQL("sqlite:///students.db")


# iterate through the csv file
with open("characters.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        middle = ""
        names = row["name"].split()

        firstname = names[0]
        if len(names) == 2:
            middle = ""
            lastname = names[1]
        else:
            middle = names[1]
            lastname = names[2]

        house = row["house"]
        birth = row["birth"]

        print(firstname)
        print(middle)
        print(lastname)
        print(row["house"])
        print(row["birth"])

        db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", firstname, middle, lastname, house, birth)
```

Attempting to view DB in the IDE

```
~/pset7/houses/ $ sqlite3 students.db
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE students (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    first VARCHAR(255),
    middle VARCHAR(255),
    last VARCHAR(255),
    house VARCHAR(10),
    birth INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
sqlite> select * from students
   ...>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the cs50 module, but perhaps try `db.commit()` after the loop completes.

Comment: Just to clarify: a `SELECT * from students;` returns no rows? (The cs50.execute method commits the data)

Comment: That's correct, no rows. I hit enter & all I get back is ...>

Comment: It's waiting for another line of input. Unlike dot commands, sql commands require a semi-colon terminator to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you forgot to put a semi-colon(;) at the end of your SELECT statement.

Try this instead:
SELECT * FROM students;